# How to add two columns using alias in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my query, I want to calculate to get the total quantity `total_qty` by adding `s.item_qty` + `grn_qty` + `issues_qty`. Is it possible to add column values using alias?

```
SELECT s.items_no, 
       s.item_desc, 
       s.item_qty, 
       (SELECT Isnull(Sum(g.qty), 0) 
        FROM   grn_details g 
        WHERE  g.items_no = s.items_no)      grn_qty, 
       (SELECT Isnull(Sum(i.qty), 0) 
        FROM   stk_issue_details i 
        WHERE  i.items_no = s.items_no)      issues_qty, 
       ( s.item_qty + grn_qty + issues_qty ) total_qty 
FROM   stocks s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in `outer query` not in same query where the `alias` is generated.

```
SELECT items_no, 
       item_desc, 
       item_qty, 
       grn_qty, 
       issues_qty, 
       total_qty = grn_qty + issues_qty 
FROM   (SELECT s.items_no, 
               s.item_desc, 
               s.item_qty, 
               (SELECT Isnull(Sum(g.qty), 0) 
                FROM   grn_details g 
                WHERE  g.items_no = s.items_no) grn_qty, 
               (SELECT Isnull(Sum(i.qty), 0) 
                FROM   stk_issue_details i 
                WHERE  i.items_no = s.items_no) issues_qty 
        FROM   stocks s) a
```

Or you can use `OUTER APPLY` where only single `select` is needed

```
SELECT s.items_no, 
       s.item_desc, 
       s.item_qty, 
       grn_qty, 
       issues_qty, 
       total_qty = grn_qty + issues_qty 
FROM   stocks s 
       OUTER apply (SELECT Isnull(Sum(g.qty), 0) 
                    FROM   grn_details g 
                    WHERE  g.items_no = s.items_no) g(grn_qty) 
       OUTER apply (SELECT Isnull(Sum(i.qty), 0) 
                    FROM   stk_issue_details i 
                    WHERE  i.items_no = s.items_no) i (issues_qty)
```